# How to set the value of multiple dropdown selectors based on the value of another dropdown selector on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: post the question and magically it starts working :/ Maybe because I removed the alert?

So I have a dropdown selector that is supposed to represent the default for a set of dropdown selectors that make up a country list.

Here is one of the many code permutations I tried:

```
$("#edit-ip-ban-setdefault").change(function () {
  var selected = this.selectedIndex
  $(".form-type-select").each(function() {
    $('.form-select').attr('selectedIndex', selected);
    $(".form-select").val(selected).change();
  });
});
```

Here is the relevant HTML for the default dropdown:

```
<select class="form-select valid" name="ip_ban_setdefault" id="edit-ip-ban-setdefault" selectedindex="1">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1"> Read Only </option> 
  <option selected="selected" value="2"> Complete Ban </option>
</select>
```

And here is the HTML for one of the many dropdowns I wish to have updated on change:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-ip-ban-AF">
  <select class="form-select valid" id="edit-ip-ban-af" name="ip_ban_AF">
    <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Read Only</option>
    <option value="2">Complete Ban</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7, but ideally the solution would work for 1.5 to 1.10.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want?

Comment: @jonju I tested the above after posting it, and it started working. Only thing I can think is I cleaned up the alerts before posting.

Comment: So your problem is solved?

Comment: @jonju yes it seems to work on Chrome and FF at least.